# Behavior of capacitor with infinite capacitance at steady state (DC analysis & AC Analysis)

Tags: voltage, capacitor, dc, impedance, resistance

What is the behavior of the capacitor below at steady state (DC/AC Analysis)?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffpv9e.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: You've got \$V_O\$ connected to ground.

Comment: What have you worked out so far? (p.s. do try the circuit diagram editor built in to this website - there's an icon in the edit toolbar)

Comment: Maybe you can find a second grader with a box of crayons to draw your schematic for you next time so that it will look neater.  Note that this site has a built-in schematic editor, so there really is no excuse for such a mess.  You wouldn't hand in homework looking like this.  We here deserve at least the same level of respect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The initial voltage across the capacitor would be 0V (uncharged). The initial current would be limited by the resistance (R) and the supply voltage (10V) **just like any other RC circuit**,  (I = 10/R amps) **but** as C is infinitely large (infinite time constant) the voltage across its plates will never rise and remain at 0V. The circuit will effectively act as a voltage source (10V) with a resistor(R) connected across it with the capacitor acting as a short circuit.

Comment: Actually the short circuit (a piece of wire) **is** a capacitor with infinite capacitance.

Comment: @johnfound, that's not correct.  By definition, an ideal wire cannot have a voltage across for any finite current through.  However, there's no contradiction in thinking of a voltage across a capacitor with infinite capacitance.  If you stop to think about it, you'll find that such a thing is indistinguishable from an ideal *voltage source*.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri - According to U=Q/C any finite charge will result in 0V on the infinite capacitance. So, in order to make any voltage higher than 0V you will need infinite charge. :P

Comment: @johnfound, and an ideal constant voltage source is an "infinite" source of energy so there's no contradiction there.  Besides, if we going to allow "infinite" anything, all bets are off.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri - The capacitor with infinite capacitance is a real device and it does have some finite serial resistance of course. :) I claim, that if there is a box with two short circuited terminals inside, one can't provide such an experiment that to distinguish this element from capacitor with infinite capacitance.

Comment: @johnfound, one cannot distinguish this element from a voltage source with \$V_S=0\$ either.  Remember, when you zero an ideal voltage source, as in the technique of superposition, the source behaves as an ideal wire.  The fact is, a hypothetical ideal capacitor with infinite capacitance is indistinguishable from an ideal constant voltage source *including the case where the voltage source voltage is zero*.

Comment: @johnfound, I just saw that I left out a word in my original comment.  I meant to write "that's not *quite* correct".  We agree that an ideal wire is equivalent to an *uncharged* capacitor with infinite capacitance.  My comment was meant to point out that we can imagine a *charged* capacitor with infinite capacitance without contradiction and this would not be identical with a wire.  I Hope that clears things up.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri - not actually. You are too concentrated on "ideal" things. IMO, a **real wire** is an equivalent of **real** capacitor with infinite capacitance and some finite serial resistance (as any normal real capacitor).

Comment: @johnfound, well I disagree with that for both practical and philosophical reasons.  So, we'll just leave it at that.  No, actually, there is one other thing.  I suppose a real open circuit is the equivalent of a real inductor with infinite inductance by your reckoning?

Comment: @AlfredCentauri - Obviously yes. An open circuit is an inductor with infinite inductance. Can you think of some experiment that to distinguish one from another?

Comment: @johnfound, then you're essentially claiming that *any* and *all* open circuits are actual, real inductors with infinite inductance; that empty space is literally *filled* with real inductors with infinite inductance.  Do you see why I find philosophical fault with your reasoning?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11023/discussion-between-johnfound-and-alfred-centauri)

Answer (score 2):

> What is the behavior of the capacitor below **at steady state (DC
>   Analysis)**?

Questions like this are fine for helping us to think a little bit harder about some of our concepts but it's always helpful to keep in mind that writing something like \$C = \infty \$ can lead to an apparent paradox.  What is better is to examine the behaviour of the circuit as \$C \rightarrow \infty \$.

As an example of an apparent paradox consider that a capacitor (with finite capacitance) is an open circuit in DC steady state because, by definition, the voltage across the capacitor is *constant* in DC steady state and thus, the capacitor current is *zero*.

\$i_C = C \cdot \dfrac{dv_C}{dt} = C \cdot 0 = 0 \$

Note that this holds for *any* value of *C* (remember \$\infty \$ is *not* a value) no matter how large.

Now, the question of what happens when \$C=\infty \$ is difficult because we have the \$\infty \cdot 0\$ form which is *ambiguous* (remember \$\infty \$ is *not* a value).

However, we *can* look at the limit as \$C \rightarrow \infty \$ while holding \$i_C\$ constant.

\$i_C = K = C \cdot \dfrac{dv_C}{dt} \$

We see that, in the limit, \$\dfrac{dv_C}{dt} \rightarrow 0 \$

In words, as C "goes to infinity", for *any* \$i_C\$, the voltage across the capacitor becomes *constant*.

Thus, we conclude that for C "equal to" infinity, a capacitor acts as an ideal constant voltage source, i.e., the voltage across is constant for *any* current through.  This means that, in a circuit like yours, there is no time variation; the voltages and current are constant with time.

Of course, there are other ways to get that result such as the one given by Jim where he points out that the time constant, *RC*, is infinite and thus, there is no time variation.